# Creating DLL to intercept change title

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

I'm from Linux background and want to implement the accepted solution in [Change the Title Bar of a Windows Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417786/change-the-title-bar-of-a-windows-executable)  on Windows platform.

I've just now created a DLL using the [msdn walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms235636.aspx)

I just want an executable to load my DLL without rebuilding the executable. I understand I need [Implicit Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx). But I'm confused about what is mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx). Since the executable will not need to call any functions from the DLL, on the contrary DLL will try to intercept change title messages.

**What setting should I choose to allow implicit linking and loading this DLL in this case?**

Comment: Why don't you do what is described in that answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No I don't think that is described there. After this, I'll come to coding of intercepting WM_SETTEXT etc.

Comment: What I mean is to ask why you don't what what the answer recommends that you do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's what I'm trying to do. If you can point me to right resources and sample code for coding .. that'd be great help. Those are missing in the answer.

Comment: That question is off-topic. Item 3 on the list here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  You should do some research, and ask specific questions when you get stuck.

Comment: I agree and I'm working on it to revise it. But I've done enough search.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a registry key called `AppInit_DLLs` that listed dlls that would be automatically loaded into every process. Since Windows Vista this now requires some hard to meet security requirements that seem overkill.

So, the next easiest way would be to use `SetWindowsHooxEx` - you would create a separate application that would monitor window creation looking for the target applications window. When it finds it, it would hook it, that would have the twofold benefit of actually intercepting the calls to WM_SETTEXT, and carry your hook dll into the target process.

This assumes that the target process is itself not elevated.

Comment: That's why I've chosen the DLL method

Answer (score 0):

For a person who just came out of Linux into Windows, this is a heavy load subject to understand. But, if you can manage to understand what is a dll, hook, windows, HWNDs, window messages (WM_) etc, then try reading this article to enhance your DLL to do hooking job, block WM_SETTEXT messages to "Windows" and call SetWindowText [Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces). Note that, most of the antivirus softwares don't like hooking applications.

BTW, what is the reason you are trying to do this?

If you are just doing it for fun, then forget hooking, try enumerating Window using [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) or use [FindWindowEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx), then simply [SendMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) or [PostMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) with WM_SETTEXT to the HWND to set title of desired window (No purpose to it, just fun and learning).